# Creating Search in a CBV ListView

Tags: django

I am building a search API for my project using the Class based View ListView. I have a problem getting into my `get_queryset` the value to be searched.

ProjectSearchListView:

```
class ProjectSearchListView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/user_project_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_queryset(self):
        query  = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            projects = Project.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=query) | Q(description__contains=query)).order_by('-date_created')
        else:
            projects = Project.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')

        return projects
```

Here is my SEARCH Form:

```
<form class="form my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'search-project' %}"  >

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control  " 
                        type="text" 
                        name="q"
                        value="{{ request.GET.q }}" 
                        aria-label="Search" 
                        placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="Search">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to include the error you are seeing, but I think you want `query = self.request.GET.get('q')`

Comment: @Mark Bailey, it spits ```request not declared```. but after changing it with your suggestion it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Great.  With the error message I could have gone straight to the problem without needing to check the other code.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` does not exist in the context of `get_queryset`.

Change it to `self.request`.